Coinbase and sending it to another wallet
The address is sent from my coinbase acct, I was tired of the shenanigans of coinbase pro, so I sent assets to a wallet I thought was more manageable.
0x587416Ba3789ee89F8B5f85FEeb836afF4D06717
And now I have no clue. My wallet address changes and I'm so not understanding any of it.
